# How to properly pipe Google Cloud Storage asset through Node.js app, to include cache headers and such

Tags: node.js, express, caching, google-cloud-storage, asset-pipeline

So I have this basically (from [here](https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/storage/2.3.x/File)):

```
const { Storage } = require('@google-cloud/storage')
const express = require('express')
const app = express()

const storage = new Storage({
  projectId: 'my-project'
})

const bucket = storage.bucket('my.bucket')

// logo and assets
app.get('/:id.:ext', (req, res) => {
  const remote = bucket.file(`${req.params.id}.${req.params.ext}`)
  remote.createReadStream().pipe(res)
})
```

I'm wondering what I need to do to set the cache headers or if it automatically somehow happens through the piping. I would like for it to permanently cache some, and 1 month cache others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to set headers in the response, you'll need to do that using the Express API.  Take a look at what you can do with the [Response](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res) object.  You'll likely want to use [res.set()](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.set).  The pipe is just going to deal with the contents of the body of the response.

Comment: how would you do it for video as I am struggling